# Multiple Ordering in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a site where I have a section for most popular lyrics. The case is that I want to Order the most pupular lyrics with respect to its ratings. And condition is, if the rating is same for two lyrics then I order by the counter which is the number of times rated.

The fields in database are rating_value and counter. For now I just using

```
".... ORDER BY rating_value";
```

Suggest me something for this kind of multiple ordering.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY rating_value DESC, rating_count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just specify more fields in the ORDER clause:

```
... ORDER BY rating_value, counter
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the columns in the order of the priority to the `ORDER BY` statement:

```
 ".... ORDER BY rating_value, counter";
```